# How to test an HTTP header value using LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, httpresponse, lwp-useragent

I may be posting more questions as I get answers, but here goes!

I am currently trying to troubleshoot a Perl script that my university used to use to automatically download files with SAT score data.

The idea is to read through emails in a certain account; pull out the cycle number (which is used in the URL); piece together multiple URLs; and then use [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) to grab the files from the server and do other Perl magicks on them.

In my investigation I have determined that manually entering the URL (and thus limiting the script to be run by the user, with the cycle number being replaced each time) actually works.

In examining the response objects sent back I noticed (first of all) that the following line is missing from the request that fails:

```
'_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
```

However it is present in the request that succeeds.

If any of you can tell me why this line is missing in the unsuccessful request you will have my thanks, but that's not what I'm asking about.

My question pertains to further investigation to see why it's being rejected.

In the documentation for `LWP::UserAgent` I noticed this:

> Error responses that LWP generates internally will have the "Client-Warning" header set to the value "Internal response". If you need to differentiate these internal responses from responses that a remote server actually generates, you need to test this header value.

**My question:** how do you actually test that header value? (Pardon any ignorance; I'm an intern in my college's IT department)

Comment: What am I misunderstanding? I'm sure you know that `'_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}` isn't a header field. It looks like the output from `Data::Dumper` to debug something within your program. I need to understand your intention and to see more of your Perl code that isn't working for you.

Comment: The absence of `_uri_canonical` just means that no one has called the `uri_canonical` method on that particular Request, which probably relates to what happens to the unsuccessful request.  The not-working script might be making that call, or it might be something like `HTTP::Config` (which would happen because of someone saying `$ua->add_handler`).  It's really hard to judge without more context.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That is actually output from Data::Dumper as you suspected. Here's the code that is giving me fits:

`code` foreach my $msgnum ( sort keys %cycles ) {
        my $url = $site.$cycles{$msgnum}{cycle};
        my $response = $browser->get($url);
        my $gpg = $response->content;
        Report($cycles{$msgnum}{cycle}, $url, $gpg, Dumper($response));

(my apologies if that formats incorrectly.) The uri_canonical bit that I mentioned above comes from the last parameter passed to the Report() sr. $browser is a basic LWP::UserAgent.

Answer (score 2):

It actually places a variety of messages in that header, which you can obtain as follows:

```
if (my $cw = $response->header('Client-Warning')) {
   die("Internal error: $cw\n");
}
```

The `Internal response` message is only used when the status already indicates an error. Other messages such as `Redirect loop detected` and `Missing Authenticate header` are used at other times. The above code will get whatever message is present there rather than just checking for `Internal response`.

Comment: Please explain your thoughts. Are you saying that there is a `Client-Warning` header in the response that can contain multiple messages? How does that relate to the question?

Comment: Using that yielded $cw = "Internal response". Thoughts?

Comment: Like I said, that means the status_line you got was generated by LWP::UA itself. What error was specified in the status line?

Comment: `code` 500 Can't connect to ets-scorelink.ets.org:443 (SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0))

Is that what you're looking for? This was another thing I was curious about.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of using `LWP` is something like

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $resp = $ua->get('http://my.domain.co.uk/');

die $resp->status_line unless $resp->is_success;

my $content = $resp->decoded_content;
```

What do you need to know?