# perl $filename vs. ./$filename in SUSE Linux Enterprise

Tags: linux, perl

Student intern working on school's Linux system, back with another question. For background, please read this question: ([How to test an HTTP header value using LWP::UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280434/how-to-test-an-http-header-value-using-lwpuseragent)).

I have made more progress on this after working on some other projects. One thing that I just happened to notice is that if I make the given script executable (using chmod) I no longer get the download error I mentioned in my first question. The strange thing (to me) is that if I run the file as `perl $filename` I get the vague, unhelpful download error, whereas if I run it as `./$filename` it works fine.

Does anyone know why that is? Feel free to ask for more clarification, but hopefully reading my other question will help with that. Thanks!

**EDIT:** My apologies! The issue is still unsolved in my mind (I will look into the potential path issue), though I have a workaround via ./script.pl. Here is the exact error message that is returned on attempting to get the file:

```
500 Can't connect to $url.org:443 (SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0))
```

Comment: This question is a bit vague and unhelpful without *the specific error you are encountering*.  :)  Please don't ask us to sift the error message out of comments in a semi-related question (with no accepted answer at present).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `perl foo` will run `foo` with the first `perl` that is found in `$PATH`.

Using `./foo` will run `foo` with whatever the first line of the script says it should run with (e.g. `#!/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/bin/perl -w`).

Working with different versions (and versions of modules) can give different results, as can running with different command line switches

Comment: You are definitely on to something here. The version specified in the script is 5.10, whereas the first version in $PATH is 5.14.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of information to go on ;-) but, considering this question in the context of your previous posting on ([How to test an HTTP header value using LWP::UserAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280434/how-to-test-an-http-header-value-using-lwpuseragent)), it at least seems possible that you are loading different versions of LWP's SSL  library  (`Crypt::SSLeay`). This can happen becasue many things depend on the path and/or command line switches you are using. For example, the `Crypt::SSLeay` contains a C code library that needs to be recompiled for the current version of the module and of perl. Perhaps you are loading the correct version (accidentally) by running `./script.pl` and a broken version when you blithely type `perl script.pl`?

If you find out what's going on please update your question :-)